# $S^{n+m}\not\simeq S^n \times S^m$ from homology induced map of inclusions being injective

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I got stuck with this problem:

> Let $X_1 , X_2$ be two topological spaces. Prove that $i_j :X_j \rightarrow X_1 \times X_2$ induces a monomorphism $H_* (i_j) :H_* (X_j) \rightarrow H_* (X_1 \times X_2)$.
>
> Conclude from this that $S^{n+m}$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S^n \times S^m$.

I think I got the first part: since the projections $p_j : X_1 \times X_2 \rightarrow X_j$ verify $p_j \circ i_j = \operatorname{Id}_{X_i}$ then $(p_j \circ i_j)_* = (p_j)_* \circ (i_j)_* = \operatorname{Id}_{H(X_i)}$ and in particular $(i_j)_*$ is injective for $j=1,2$. However I don't see how to connect this with the second question. I've tried to use that for homotopy equivalent spaces $X$ and $Y$, $H_n (X)$ is isomorphic to $H_n (Y)$ for all $n$, but with no result.

Comment: By the first part, the inclusion $S^n \to S^n \times S^m$ induces an inclusion on homology. What does that tell you about $H_n(S^n \times S^m)$? What do you know about $H_n(S^{n+m})$?

Comment: @William got it! thanks